# How to keep a trailing zero when printing a float without setting precision?

Tags: rust, floating-point

Given a whole floating point number, Rust does not include any decimals when converting it to a string. I want a way to keep the `.0` around without setting a fixed precision since I like the default formatting for numbers that do have decimals ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d948e4c4bc9cd36d80b548c0e9a1e029)):

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", 1.0);
    println!("{}", 1.1999999);
    println!("{:.1}", 1.0);
    println!("{:.1}", 1.999999)
}
```

```
1
1.1999999
1.0
2.0
```

So I would like to be able to print that extra `.0` without it affecting anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to keep the additional `.0`, differentiating it from an integer, is to use the `Debug` formatter:

```
println!("{:?}", 1.0);
println!("{:?}", 1.1999999);
```

```
1.0
1.1999999
```

I don't see a way to dictate this behavior with the precision format specifier since providing a precision uses that as an "exact" precision, and without it internally uses a "min" precision of `0` and `1` for `Display` and `Debug` respectively. ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/float.rs.html))